# incompatible operand types r.integer and int

Tags: java, android, int

I am trying to compare the integer type list and position in the spinner. The integer list contains the list of IDs from a database and the spinner contains the list of names with respect to the IDs. The IDs and names are stored in a database, after comparing the ID from the list and the position from the spinner, two edit text boxes are set to the values corresponding to the specific ID other than name.
The ID is set to auto increment. 
Here is the MainActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b;
EditText ed1, ed2, ed3;
Spinner sp;
String url = "https://web.facebook.com/";
String urltest = "http://www.google.com/";
WebView wb;
database db;
String details[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    db = new database(LoginActivity.this);

    // wb.loadUrl(url);
    List<String> l = db.userlist();
    final List<Integer> idlist = db.IDList();
    ArrayAdapter<String> sa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, l);
    sp.setAdapter(sa);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user u = new user();
            String name = ed1.getText().toString();
            String uname = ed2.getText().toString();
            String pass = ed3.getText().toString();

            if (name.length() > 0 && uname.length() > 0 && pass.length() > 0) {
                u.setName(name);
                u.setUname(uname);
                u.setPass(pass);

                db.insert(u);
                ed1.setText("");
                ed2.setText("");
                ed3.setText("");

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter the Name, User Name and password",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The user name details has been saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (idlist.get(position) == position) {
                details = db.details(position);
                ed2.setText(details[0]);
                ed3.setText(details[1]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

}

I have created two other java files as database.java which creates database and returns:

```
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String dbname = "Personal";
    public static int version = 1;
    public static String tblname = "Data";
    public static String id = "ID";
    public static String name = "Name";
    public static String uname = "Username";
    public static String pass = "Password";

    public database(Context context) {
        super(context, dbname, null, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql1 = "create table " + tblname + " (" + id + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + name + " text, "
                + uname + " text, " + pass + " text)";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    void insert(user u) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(name, u.getName());
        values.put(uname, u.getUname());
        values.put(pass, u.getPass());

        db.insert(tblname, id, values);
    }

    public List<String> userlist() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(tblname, new String[] { name }, null, null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String data = cursor.getString(0);
            list.add(data);
            // Log.e("1", data);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public List<integer> IDList() {
        List<integer> idlist = new ArrayList<integer>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(tblname, new String[] { id }, null, null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String data = cursor.getString(0);
            idlist.add(Integer.parseInt(data), null);
        }
        return idlist;

    }

    public String[] details(int position) {
        String username = null, password=null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(tblname, new String[] { id, uname, pass }, null, null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            if (position == cursor.getInt(0)) {
                username = cursor.getString(1);
                password = cursor.getString(2);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return new String[] {username, password};

    }

}
```

and a user.java to get and set the details:

```
public class user {

    String id, name, uname, pass;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }


}
```

I was getting an error in `MainActivity.java` file as `incompatible operand types r.integer and int`. This is on the line `if(idlist.get(position)==position)` ---- It is in the spinner set on item selected listener which is now solved by changing integer to Integer. But the statement is somehow invalid. It cannot compare Integer and int. Any suggestions to rectify it?

Comment: Is your code compiling? Normaly `Integer` starts with an uppercase `i` or is it not a `java.util.Integer`?

Comment: @Jens - I guess it's compiling all right AND android has an 'integer' class which describes int resources. But that's just guessing

Comment: There is an error due to incompatible operand types but converting integer to Integer did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'integer' really exists as a [nested class of class 'R'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html)
. So your List was interpreted as a List for data type R.integer, but 'R.integer' and the primitive data type 'int' are not compatible.

As the purpose of class 'Integer' is to turn integer numbers into objects when needed, it is not compatible as well.

**EDIT:**
So the first thing you want to do is to change every 'integer' in your code to 'Integer', because you want to deal with numbers, not with android resources.

Looking at the method where your crash occurred, it's a bit difficult to tell what you need to do to make your code work (not just 'not crash').

The 'position' value in your 'onItemSelected()' method will give you the index of your List 'l' corresponding to the selected ListView row.

Now you seem to check wether the list index of one user name is equal to the userid in your SQLite DB. As I don't know your data model, I can't tell wether doing so makes sense. I only know that you did fill 'idlist' and 'l' by separate queries into the database and you included no 'ORDER BY', so maybe the names and the ids will even not be ordered the same way.

But that's another question... :)

Comment: Yes, it is also not working. Can you suggest the right way to do it?

Comment: @ArpitKumar - Ok, I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

There is a difference between `integer` and `Integer`.

Try to use this, I hope it will help you.

Comment: By converting all integer to Integer did the trick but why so many different types for integer as int, integer and Integer?

Comment: Integer is a wrapper class which is basically using for parsing and int are data types ehich are commonly used in code.

Comment: I don't know what you intended to do with `<I>`, but you might check if you really need it.

Comment: @Tom: Where should I add this statement? The list in this case is getting value from a function in databse.java file. Do I have to edit the function itself? What should be the syntax? 0X0nosugar said correctly Integer and int cannot be compared. The code is compiling but it crashes before even it starts.

Comment: Please edit your question if you have new information. But please _append/add_ these information, don't remove stuff from your current question.